# Desktop notifications will not work under Ubuntu 22.04 and Unity DE

Tags: unity, notification

I'm using a PC with Ubuntu 22.04
I recently installed the Unity DE (with the Light DM option if I recall correctly). I have since encountered a couple of issues I would like to resolve but will need assistance.
Entering the command: *notify-send "Test"* in a terminal window causes a long delay, then the message: *Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.Notifications: Timeout was reached.*
If I login under Ubuntu, or Plasma DE options, the notifications work fine, but I'm beginning to like the features in Unity DE.
I have created a systemd unit to run remind (which includes a notify-send command) when resuming after suspend and it seems to be causing a slow resume.
My second issue is that RTCWAKE has become unreliable. I'm hoping that correcting the notifications issue will resolve that too.
Any suggestions would be appreciated. If any further details or information is required, please let me know and I will provide it.